# How to make text fade in and out for different sentences in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on Javascript. I want some sentences that should fade out after 10 seconds and go to the next. I don't want it in jQuery so trying it in JS.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <p id="hide1">Hide 1</p>
    <p id="hide2">Hide 2</p>
    <p id="hide2">Hide 3</p>
    <p id="hide2">Hide 4</p>
    <p id="hide2">Hide 5</p>
    <p id="hide2">Hide 6</p>
```

Example I want like this is: http://jsfiddle.net/5g21tqdc/1/

Any help?

Comment: where did you defined `p` and `element`?

Comment: How about CSS transition? and use JavaScript to simply change the class name on timeout.

Comment: Or simply CSS animation, no JS at all.

Comment: I didnt get the expected output so asking here

Comment: how to do in CSS then any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example use 0.1s fade-in and 10s fade-out.

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");

function cycle() {
  ps.forEach((p, i) => {
    const s = p.style;
    setTimeout(() => {
      ps.forEach(p => {
        p.style.display = "";
        p.style.opacity = "0";
      });
      s.display = "block";
      s.transition = "opacity .1s";
      s.opacity = "1";
      setTimeout(() => {
        s.transition = "opacity 10s";
        s.opacity = "0";
      }, 100);
    }, i * 10100);
  });
  setTimeout(cycle, ps.length * 10100);
}
cycle();
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="hide1">Hide 1</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 2</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 3</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 4</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 5</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 6</p>
```

Comment: But thanks for the answer

Comment: @ishaanu It replicates the same effects in your example exactly. How can you say it is not giving the correct output?

Comment: Amazing this works like a pro.

Comment: But i have one problem here is after loading the page all the p tag elements are appearing at once and disappearing and after that this code starts. I want to eliminate that is that possible?

Comment: @ishaanu Yes, added CSS.

Answer (score 2):

First, define the CSS animation.

Then, set the animation with delay via JavaScript or hard code in CSS.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach((p, i) =>
    p.style.animation = `fade 10.1s ${i * 10.1}s`
);
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        font-size: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    0.16% {
        font-size: initial;
    }
    1% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        font-size: initial;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
p {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="hide1">Hide 1</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 2</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 3</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 4</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 5</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 6</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to use an [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) delay set to the number of elements, then cycle opacity between 0 and 1.

There's a bit of hardcoding going on here with the keyframe percentages and a CSS preprocessor or separate ids per `<p>` element could be used to avoid JS, so consider it a proof of concept. Since `display` can't be animated, I used `position: absolute` to overlap elements. I also took the liberty to speed up the animation but it should be easy to adjust to fit your needs.

```js
const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")];

elems.forEach((e, i) => {
  e.style.animationDuration = `${elems.length * 2000}ms`;
  e.style.animationDelay = `${i * 2000}ms`;
});
```

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<p>Hide 1</p>
<p>Hide 2</p>
<p>Hide 3</p>
<p>Hide 4</p>
<p>Hide 5</p>
<p>Hide 6</p>
```

This can also be done in JS. The version below uses `setTimeout` aligned to match the opacity duration and is easily adjustable.

```js
const speedMs = 2000;
const fadeInMs = speedMs * 0.1;
const fadeOutMs = speedMs * 0.9;
const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")];

const fade = (e, fadeIn, fadeOut) => {
  Object.assign(e.style, {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: `opacity ${fadeIn}ms`,
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    Object.assign(e.style, {
      opacity: 0,
      transition: `opacity ${fadeOut}ms`,
    });
  }, fadeIn);
};

elems.forEach((e, i) => {
  Object.assign(e.style, {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    opacity: 0,
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    fade(e, fadeInMs, fadeOutMs);
    setInterval(fade, speedMs * elems.length, 
                e, fadeInMs, fadeOutMs);
  }, i * speedMs);
});
```

```html
<p>Hide 1</p>
<p>Hide 2</p>
<p>Hide 3</p>
<p>Hide 4</p>
<p>Hide 5</p>
<p>Hide 6</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

This example shows each `p` being hidden one at a time:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
inputs.forEach(function(el,index,array){           
    setTimeout( (function( index ) {
      return function() {
          el.classList.add("hidden");
      };
  }( index)), (1000 * index) );            
})
```

```css
.hidden
{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<p id="hide1">Hide 1</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 2</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 3</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 4</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 5</p>
<p id="hide2">Hide 6</p>
```

Comment: This is good but i need one after the other hide 1 and the next hide 2 like that here you are displaying all the items at once

Comment: Can you develop some code and sent it once again?

Comment: My answer has been updated.